# How to display chosen option from dropdown list?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to ask help as to how I can display the selected option from my dropdown list. My dropdown list currently contains options "Building 1" and "Building 2". So if ever user selects "Building 1" for example, it must appear on dropdown list after he/she clicks the "Submit" button beside it. It will stay as is unless he/she clicks on another option.

Here is a snippet of the code I've done so far but doesn't seem to work:

```
<!--Building dropdown contents-->
<form name="bldg_form" method="post">
<select name="bldg" id="soflow">
  <option value="">Choose Building</option>;
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bquery)) : ?>
      <option value="<?= $row['building_ID'] ?>" <?= $row['building_name'] == $selectedbldg?>><?= $row['building_name'] ?></option>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="view" />
</form>
```

Everytime I click the Submit button, it goes back to displaying the default, "Choose Building".

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create the `selected` attribute but, it's actually `echo` a boolean instead of `"selected"`:

Should be:

```
<?= $row['building_name'] == $selectedbldg ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
```

Because `<?= $row['building_name'] == $selectedbldg?>` will write a boolean, in this case `"1"` or `""`.

Then, the posted value is `building_ID`, so, the comparison should be with this value.

The option tag:

```
<option value="<?= $row['building_ID'] ?>" 
    <?= $row['building_ID'] == $selectedbldg ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
><?= $row['building_name'] ?></option>
```

Comment: Oh I see.Thanks @Syscall! :) I fixed my code however, its still the same problem. :(

Comment: The condition shouldn't be `$row['building_ID'] == $selectedbldg` instead?